# How can i remove a specified field from a mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to remove dynamically a field from a mongoose document.

**What I have tried:**
I am using

```
$unset
```

and when I type the value

```
"cars.BMW"
```

it works. But when I want to pass a parameter, which will be a car brand and then to unset it. I tried

```
{$unset: {"cars."+brand: " "}}
```

but the plus sign is unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring and Template literals:

```
{$unset: {[`cars.${brand}`]: " "}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation doesn't work like that. In js, you would use bracket notation to create a property dynamically from a string.

```
exports.deleteBrand = function(req, res){ 
    var brand = req.params.brand;
    var query = {};
    query["cars." + brand] = "";
    Text.update(
        {key: req.params.key},
        {$unset: query},
        function(err){ if(err) res.send(err);
        res.json({message: "Car deleted!"}); 
    });
}
```

The query variable here translates to: `{"cars.bmw": ""}` if the brand is "bmw".

EDIT: Edited to match the method by op.

Comment: `exports.deleteBrand = function(req, res){
 var brand = req.params.brand;

 Text.update({key: req.params.key}, {$unset: {cars[brand]: ""}}, function(err){
  if(err)
   res.send(err);

  res.json({message: "Car deleted!"});
 })
}` This is the function which I want to use to remove a specific brand. Here it says that the token [ is unexpected (cars[brand]).

Comment: @kirpt: Can you please post a snippet of data? Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code. It sends the message that the brand is deleted but it is still in the database.

Comment: Really hard to say what happens and what doesn't without a visual on the data. Post a snippet of the data in your question and one example of the request parameter "key", so I can help you further :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$unset** to remove feld, here is the example:

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {confirmationKey: req.params.key}, 
    {isConfirmed: true, $unset: { confirmationKey: ""}}, {}, (err, doc) => {

    if (err) {
      res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send(StatusGen.getError(err))
    } else {
      console.log('user = ' + JSON.stringify(doc))
      res.send(StatusGen.getSuccess('confirmed'))
    }
  })
```

Now field confirmationKey is is deleted.